# How do I get the foreach value in another page?

Tags: php

once the form has been submitted I will get the `checkbox` values and stored in `$segment.Based` on `$segment` value .I am showing `form.From` that form I am sending some values to  next page(final.php) not segment values, but I want to get the `$segment` value here for  that what I have to do?

*Note:$segment value is array.can any one help me*

Here tutorsubject.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $segment=$_POST['segment'];
      echo $segment;
    }
   ?>
    <form name="f1" action="tutorsubject.php" method="post">
    <p>Teaching segment
    <input type="checkbox" name="segment[]" value="Engineering">Engineering
    <input type="checkbox" name="segment[]" value="Technology">Technology
    <input type="checkbox" name="segment[]" value="Dances">Dance
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Now

```
    <form name="f1" action="final.php" method="post"/>
   Name:<input type="Text" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="submit"  name="Submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Final.php Here I am  getting final.php values based on . In Final.php I want to get the $segment values for what I have to do

Comment: See how SESSIONs work.

Comment: i'm sorry your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use session:

```
$_SESSION["segment"] = $segment;
```

and to read it in your final.php page:

```
print_r($_SESSION["segment"]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I agree, sessions might be a good way for you to go with this. PHP is stateless remember.

Comment: An other way is to use hidden fields

Comment: @LucaOlivieri The variable ($segment) is an array, thats why i think he would better to use session unless he wants to serialize the variable and pass it through.